# Get Previous Element From a List // Java

Tags: java

I am getting data from a csv. If a row in csv doesn't contain values, I will need to update it with the previous row values. The way I am doing it is -

1. Parse the csv and add all the rows to a linked list.
2. Iterate through the list and check if a row is empty then fill it with the previous row.

Point #2 is not working as expected. Below is my code snippet:

```
    ListIterator<Data> li = dataList.listIterator(0);
    while (li.hasNext()) {
        Data prev = null;
        if (li.hasPrevious()) {
            prev = li.previous();
            System.out.println("Previous Node is: "+prev);
        }
        Data data = li.next();
        if (data.getNumber() == null || data.getNumber().trim().isEmpty()) {
            data.setPartType(prev.getPartType());
            data.setNumber(prev.getNumber());
        }
```

I believe its happening because when we call `next()` it moves the pointer to the next and hence the previous element will be the current element.

Question - how do I get the actual previous element?

Comment: This is a `NullPointerException` waiting to happen if the first row is empty, by the way. The code in the second `if` should check whether `prev` is not null before calling methods on it.

Comment: By the way, move `Data data = li.next();` to the beginning of the loop. The first call to `next()` will return the first element of the list since you passed `0` to the `listIterator` method.

Comment: Do not use while and hasnext instead use for and indices

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks. Moving the `next()` to the top will still not give me the previous element because `next()` will move the pointer.

Comment: You're right, both `next` and `previous` move the pointer. I'd say David Brossard is right, use a normal `for` loop with indexes. It will be a lot easier and a lot easier to follow too.

Comment: Was able to get it with for loop and indices. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) `listIterator.previous()` and `listIterator.next()` moves the cursor position backwards and forwards respectively. Hence, in your case it'll mostly result in a endless loop at 2nd index.

What you essentially need is previous element without moving cursor. `listIterator.previousIndex()` can help you with it.

```
ListIterator<Data> li = dataList.listIterator(0);

while (li.hasNext()) {
    Data prev = null;
    if (li.hasPrevious()) {
        prev = dataList.get(li.previousIndex());
        System.out.println("Previous Node is: "+prev.getNumber());
    }
    Data data = li.next();
    if (data.getNumber() == null || data.getNumber().trim().isEmpty()) {
        data.setPartType(prev.getPartType());
        data.setNumber(prev.getNumber());
    }
}
```

Although this seems to clutter the readability of code. Better to consider using a simple forEach loop. As -

```
Data prev = null;
for (Data data: dataList) {
    if ((data.getNumber() == null || data.getNumber().trim().isEmpty()) && prev != null) {
        data.setPartType(prev.getPartType());
        data.setNumber(prev.getNumber());
    }
    prev = data;
}
```